# Image resource is not showed on device using IONIC

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I want to show an image using IONIC and Angular.js but it's only showed on the Ripple web emulator, it's doesn't appears on the device.

I am tried the following code:

a) Set this directly in the view (login.html)

```
<img src="[image_path]"/> <!-- Evidently... ;) -->
```

b) The same but using ng-src attribute

```
<img ng-src="[image path]"/>
```

c) .... or using MVC model:

```
//in controllert.js:

$cordovaFile.readAsDataUrl('[image_path]').then(
function(res) { 
 $scope.imgSrc = res; 
}
function(error) {
 alert('Something was wrong'); 
}
);

//in view (login.html):

<img src=“{{ imgSrc }}“ />
```

The most strange is that if  is commented in      index.html, a simple img tag with the resource works perfeclty! :(

Somebody has any idea about why this is not working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**

I don't know exactly why but it works (at least in my case) setting the resources folder into the templates folder, then you just need to use a simple img tag.

[image]